# problems with django raw query parameters

Tags: django, django-queryset

I was trying to make a custom raw query for a model and i get this error:

> DatabaseError: error de sintaxis en o cerca de
>   «E'positions_statusrecord'» LINE 1: SELECT id FROM
>   E'positions_statusrecord' WHERE "type"=E'Leav...

Here is the raw query i'm trying to use (it's a manager method):

```
def get_status_ids(self, model):
    """
    This query returns the latest statuses ids for each entry
    of "model" in StatusRecord.
    """
    db_table = self.model._meta.db_table
    model_type = model.get_status_type()

    raw_query = (
        "SELECT id "
        "FROM %s "
        "WHERE \"type\"=%s AND "
        "(identifier,date_time) IN "
               "( "
                          "SELECT identifier, Max(date_time) "
                          "FROM %s "
                          "WHERE \"type\"=%s "
                          "GROUP BY identifier"
               ")"
    )

    params = (db_table, model_type, db_table, model_type, )
    return self.raw(raw_query, params)
```

I've tried with a simpler query (just a `SELECT ... FROM ..`) and had the same problem. It seems to be that raw queries couldn't have the `FROM` part completed with a parameter.

Am i right? or have i made a mistake and i'm not finding it?

I'm using postgreSQL 8.4.10, django 1.3 and python 2.6.

I've searched information about raw queries parameters to see if there are some forbidden formatting options, but i didn't find anything that helps me.

Does anyone knows what's causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to be that raw queries couldn't have the "FROM" part completed with a parameter.

Yes, the ORM will quote the string argument making it `... FROM 'some_table' ...`.

Since the db_table parameter is trusted (not originated from user input), you can do something like:

```
raw_query = (
    "SELECT id "
    "FROM %s "
    "WHERE \"type\"=%%s AND "
    "(identifier,date_time) IN "
           "( "
                      "SELECT identifier, Max(date_time) "
                      "FROM %s "
                      "WHERE \"type\"=%%s "
                      "GROUP BY identifier"
           ")"
) % (db_table, db_table)
return self.raw(raw_query, (model_type, model_type))
```

Since [Django Aggregation can be used in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses), probably you can get the same results without resorting to raw SQL (look also the [`in` lookup example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)).

Look if you can replace `raw()` with `QuerySet.extra()` and SQL `IN` with `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I thought that it was always recommended to pass arguments to raw queries in the "params" argument. I'm a newbie in security issues so i've tried to use it always in that way. But it's true that it's a trusted input in this case.

About the "EXISTS" issue, i think i did that before, but in another way, and i had some performance problems. If i am right, that query would make a subquery for every entry in the table and the table has a lot of entries in it (more than 2000). Although i think i had done this, i would give it a try again. Thank you very much!

Comment: @marianobianchi: 2000 entries is fairly small, you may see no difference between `IN` and `EXISTS`.